# How are CSS elements combined

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got several CSS elements that I'd like to group.

At the moment I'm using:

```
.elementA {
    padding: 3px;
}

.elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

I'd like to combine them into one rule to avoid repeating stuff over and over again. E.g.

```
.elementA and .elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.elementA,.elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Reference http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000152.php

Answer (score 4):

```
.elementA, .elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

by comma separator `,` you can combine

Answer (score 2):

```
.elementA, .elementB { padding: 3px; }
```

The comma is the combiner.

Answer (score 1):

```
.elementA, .elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

uSed to this

```
.elementA, .elementB{
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Used the `(,)` Comma

Answer (score 1):

Just separate your classes with a comma

```
.elementA, .elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the comma (`,`)

```
.elementA, .elementB {
    padding: 3px;
}
```